# After DB2 instance and DB update (11.5.7 -> 11.5.8) federation doesn't work

Tags: db2-luw, db2-11.5

After installing the 11.5.8.0 FixPack and updating the DB the federation to MS SQL doesn't work. Except the federation to MSSQL the DB itself and other features works perfectly.

I've edited the odbc.ini file and corrected binary paths from 11.5.7 to 11.5.8 and it doesn't help.

What tasks should I consider to make it work?